# Extracting the data from SQL Server filtered by username

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a huge table `tableA` in my database. I have to extract the entries made into this `tableA` by `userA`.

My aim is to append this data in one more server where we give the build.

The query

```
select * 
from tableA 
where name = 'userA'
```

will give the select statements. But how to get the insert statements as a script, so that when I run in a new db, all the entries should be inserted into the new table?

To conclude, I want to extract and give the script to a build person of all the records made by me as a script.

Comment: why generate a scripts ? there is built in generate script in sql where you can get all the data from 1 table.

Comment: That tool will give the data for the entire table which includes the entries from other users. And this table contains 1 million records

Comment: I see, is that new db in the same server ? , if that is the same server you can do that directly , by calling the database name or by using Synonyms

Comment: Nope , its a different server altogether

Comment: Have you considered SSIS if this is a regular scheduled process?

Comment: No, this is just one time activity

Comment: If that is the case, then the choice is to backup your table and it's data then export it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a script to insert into a new table (TableB) from the table A?
If the table are in the same server, you need only make:

```
Insert into TableB (Col1, Col2, Col3)
select Col1, Col2, Col3 from TableA
```

If the tables are in a different server. First you have to make a Linked Server between the servers and after execute the script

```
Insert into Server2.TableB (Col1, Col2, Col3)
select Col1, Col2, Col3 from Server1.TableA
```

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, if you don't have columns with NULL values you could try this sequence of queries:

```
#get fields in a mysql variable

select   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', `column_name`, '`')) 
from `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` where TABLE_NAME='tableA' into @fields;

#get the query which will generate the insert command in a variable

select CONCAT("SELECT CONCAT(\'INSERT INTO tableA(",@fields,
")VALUES(\\\'\',CONCAT_WS(\"\',\'\",",@fields,
"),\"\');\") as `INSERT COMMAND` from `tableA` where `name`='userA'")
into @generateInsertCommand;

#execute the query which will generate insert command

PREPARE stmt FROM @generateInsertCommand;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

it should generate something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tableA(`id`,`date1`,`int1`,`name`)VALUES('4','2015-10-21','127','userA');
INSERT INTO tableA(`id`,`date1`,`int1`,`name`)VALUES('5','2015-10-20','327','userA');
```